# Element-wise weighted average of multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have 3 dataframes (df1, df2, df3). I know I can get an element-wise average of the three dataframes with

```
list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
sum(list_of_dfs)/len(list_of_dfs)
```

But I need to get a weighted average of the three dataframes, with weights defined in an array "W"

```
W = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.5])
```

So df1 will get a 20% weight, df2 30% and df3 50%.
Unfortunately the actual number of dataframes is much larger than 3, otherwise I could do simply the follwing:

```
df1*W[0] + df2*W[1] + df3*W[2]
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the sum with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
sum(w*d for w, d in zip(W, list_of_dfs))
```

For the average, divide by the sum of weights if it's not already equal to `1`:

```
sum(w*d for w, d in zip(W, list_of_dfs))/sum(W)
```

Or, with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) (assuming the DataFrames are aligned):

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.average(np.dstack(list_of_dfs), axis=2, weights=W),
                   index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
```

Example output (weighted average):

```
     0    1    2    3    4
0  1.9  2.0  4.0  4.6  4.4
1  6.4  3.5  3.9  2.7  6.2
2  6.3  2.6  4.2  5.1  5.0
3  8.4  5.6  4.4  6.3  3.3
4  1.9  3.9  6.2  6.9  2.8
```

Used input:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 5)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 5)))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 5)))
```