# Calculate weighted average for every row in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe :

```
data = {'a': [76,65,32,43,43],
        'number of a': [4,4,4,3,4],
        'b': [75,98,56,90,88],
        'number of b' : [7,6,7,2,2],
        'c': [54,44,65,76,66],
        'number of c': [9,'',1,3,6]}

# Creates DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.Dataframe(data)
```

| a | number of a | b | number of b | c | number of c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76 | 4 | 75 | 7 | 54 | 9 |
| 65 | 4 | 98 | 6 | 44 |  |
| 32 | 4 | 56 | 7 | 65 | 1 |
| 43 | 3 | 90 | 2 | 76 | 3 |
| 43 | 4 | 88 | 2 | 66 | 6 |

I'm trying to find the weighted mean of columns `a, b, and c` using the `number of...` columns as weight.

I tried using the following code, but I was wondering if there was a more straightforward way to accomplish this.

```
df['avg'] = ((df['a'].fillna(0)*df['number of a'].fillna(0)) + 
            (df['b'].fillna(0)*df['number of b'].fillna(0)) + 
            (df['c'].fillna(0)*df['number of c'].fillna(0)))/
            (df['number of a'].fillna(0) + df['number of b'].fillna(0) + df['number of c'].fillna(0))
```

Comment: please fix your calculation it is throwing: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a better way

```
c = pd.Index(['a', 'b', 'c'])

X, W = df[c], df['number of ' + c]
df['avg'] = X.mul(W.values).sum(axis=1) / W.sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
    a  number of a   b  number of b   c  number of c     avg
0  76            4  75            7  54          9.0  65.750
1  65            4  98            6  44          NaN  84.800
2  32            4  56            7  65          1.0  48.750
3  43            3  90            2  76          3.0  67.125
4  43            4  88            2  66          6.0  62.000
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible option :

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/75697792/16120011
tmp = df.fillna(0)

S = [tmp["a"], tmp["b"], tmp["c"]]
W = [tmp["number of a"], tmp["number of b"], tmp["number of c"]]

df["avg"] = sum(w * s for (w, s) in zip(W, S)) / sum(W)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

    a  number of a   b  number of b   c  number of c     avg
0  76            4  75            7  54          9.0  65.750
1  65            4  98            6  44          NaN  84.800
2  32            4  56            7  65          1.0  48.750
3  43            3  90            2  76          3.0  67.125
4  43            4  88            2  66          6.0  62.000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['wt_avg']=df.fillna(0).apply(lambda x:((x['a']*x['number of a']+x['b']*x['number of b']+x['c']*x['number of c'])/
                   x[['number of a','number of b','number of c']].sum()),axis=1)
print(df)
    a   number of a   b number of b    c    number of c wt_avg
0   76     4         75        7      54          9.0   65.750
1   65     4         98        6      44          NaN   84.800
2   32     4         56        7      65          1.0   48.750
3   43     3         90        2      76          3.0   67.125
4   43     4         88        2      66          6.0   62.000
```